# " I am at John " Can this mean that I am very near to him?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammaticality, phrase-meaning

What is The correct preposition for saying that I am  very near to someone and can reach him easily and in the same place where he is ?  Can I use at " I am at John ". Please note that I do not want to say the I am in his house but just want to say that I am near him and can reach him easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to say that you are at reachable distance to that of John, then you can say: "I am near to John.". ["Near to"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/near-and-near-to) means 'not far away in distance'.

Answer (score 2):

You're *at* a place, and *John* is not a place. If you say *I'm at John*, people will think you made a mistake and you mean you're *at John's*.

If you are near to John, you can just say that: *I'm near to John*.
Alternatively, you can change the point of view around if you want to tell someone that John is near you: *John is (right) here*.

Comment: You could say "I am at John's" (where the implication is "John's house/office/car/body/etc" as appropriate)